# Combine 2 css files into one

Tags: html, css

I have 2 css files . 90% of them is the same but the 10% is different . for example the 1st file have the 90% classes and the other 10% are some classes for different screens. the 2nd file has the same first 90% and the other 10% are new classes i made. i want to merge both to have the  first 90% and the other 10% from both files into a single new file. any ideas how to?

Comment: Yes, you can easily merge them using a simple diff tool.

Comment: How many rules are there? Can you do it by-hand?

Comment: @JimmyLoyola A simple diff tool won't respect CSS selector order and specificity rules.

Comment: How different are they? if they are completely different, you could try some tools to sort them by rules and selectors in order to have less diffs as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone . turns out vs code has a feature for this by selecting the 2 files in open editors and then compare:
[image: css]